# No updating code when executing angularjs project using http-server

Tags: angularjs, httpserver

I create my angularjs project. I install http-server using `npm install -g http server`. And then i run using `http-server`. 
My problem is that when i change my code nothing is changed in the brower. How can i fix this problem please.

Comment: Can you provide code examples please?

Comment: is the browser caching? i usually have the console open and the "do not cache" tickbox checked.

Comment: Automatically? Or  when pressing F5? Do you have some gulp or grunt running?

Comment: Th e problem is not with code , it's related to the server. When i press F5 nothing is changed.

Comment: I get the solution . I must press F5 but i select the URL page and then i press enter. That was my problem